# Is there a way for me to modify the size of the circle in nvd3's interactive layer?

Tags: nvd3.js

NVD3's interactive layer has circles/points that highlight a point in the line of a linechart when your mouse hovers over the chart. Is there a way to change the size of that circle? My aim is to make it smaller.

Here are the circles I'm talking about.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By Increasing the stroke-width in css.

```
.nv-scatter .nv-groups .nv-point.hover, .nvd3 .nv-groups
.nv-point.hover {
      stroke-width: 14px; //(7px -> 14 px)  
      fill-opacity: .5 !important;
      stroke-opacity: .5 !important;
 }
```